# How to define a parametric type over parametric type?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have types

```
immutable X{T}
    a::T
end

immutable Y{T}
    a::T
end
```

I would like to do something like

```
type A{T, U}
    x::U{T}
    y::T
end
```

So that the instances could be `A(X(a), a)` or `A(Y(a), a)`

It doesn't work as 
`LoadError: TypeError: Type{...} expression: expected Type{T}, got TypeVar`

What's the correct way for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, `U` is a `TypeVar`, not a `Type`. The answer is to make `U` a real type:

```
julia> abstract U{T}

julia> immutable X{T} <: U{T}
           a::T
       end

julia> immutable Y{T} <: U{T}
           a::T
       end

julia> type A{T}
           x::U{T}
           y::T
       end

julia> A(X(1),1)
A{Int64}(X{Int64}(1),1)

julia> A(X(1),1.)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching A{T}(::X{Int64}, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  A{T}{T}(::U{T}, ::T) at REPL[4]:2
  A{T}{T}(::Any) at sysimg.jl:53

julia> A(Y(1),1)
A{Int64}(Y{Int64}(1),1)
```

Comment: But then A.x is abstract type rather than concrete type. Wouldn't that hurt performance?

Comment: @colinfang i guess you are actually looking for something like this `type A{T, U<:Union{X{T},Y{T}}}`, but triangular dispatch is still not supported in julia for now. currently, you can use `type A{T, U<:Union{X,Y}}` + inner constructor as a workaround. hopefully we'll have triangular dispatch [in julia-0.6](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6984#issuecomment-49751358).

Comment: I believe that master currently has triangular dispatch, so it definitely should be in 0.6